# What blog engines are available that can run in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to experiment with this Google service, and I'm also interested in playing around with python.

What are some python based blog engine frameworks that are easy to set up with Google's AppEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your answer from here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086465/blog-engine-for-google-app-engine